# angular absolute routes and route/stateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just have a problem with angular routes.
I have a singlePage Application with 4 different views.
I'm using the ui.router for `$stateProvider`.
The main view is on route: `https://testsite.com/`
If I'm wanted to get to the page  like: `https://testsite.com/view1` i have an error. It is working if I'm on the main view and then changing the route on a click event like:

```
$scope.go = function ( path ) {
    $location.path( path );
};
```

, but if i give the absolute url for the browser, it wont work.

Here is my index.html:

```
<body>
<div ui-view></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/libs/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

view1:

```
<div class="first-container">
//some content here
</div>
```

view2:

```
<div class="second-conteiner">
//some content here
</div>
```

and my App.js:

```
var app = angular.module('SofticApp',['ngRoute', 'ui.router']);
app.config(function($routeProvider,$stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
  $locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
  }).hashPrefix('!');
$stateProvider
  .state( '/', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'assets/views/view1.html',
    controller: 'viewFirstController'
  })
  .state( '/view2',{
    url: '/view2',
    templateUrl: 'assets/views/view2.html',
    controller: 'viewSecondController'
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

dont use the absolute url, use the path only

alternatively use

```
$state.go('view2')
```

notice that the state name should be 'view2' NOT '/view2'